# How to install and use Jade

Tags: node.js, web, pug

Recently I was watching some video tutorials on youtube and came across this JADE thing, how do I install and use it for my web development?

I googled it around but didn't find a proper site that teaches step-by-step to proceed with. And the site jade-lang.com is not available. I did this from websites but node.js is throwing some errors. screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: The error literally tells you the problem, how much simpler could it be?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first` jade is deprecated and new name for jade is pug for more information about this check this link

[pug documentation](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)

`second` to install pug write this command `npm install pug -g` after you install pug create a new folder to your project and create a file inside your project `file.pug` and `right click` on your folder project `+ shift`
and `open command window here` and write this command `pug file.pug` after you write this command it will generate a new file `file.html`

`Third` write this command  `pug input.pug input.html --watch --pretty`

`--watch` to compile your code after saving in file.pug

`--pretty` to write a code with format of html(organized code) not `minimized code`

to write a tag in pug write the name of tag like

- `html` tag and we will compile to `<html></html>`
- `a(href='#' target='_blank') link` compile to `<a href="#" target="_blank">link</a>`
- `a(href='#' target=''): img(src='' alt='')` compile to `<a href="#" target=""><img src="" alt=""/></a>`
- to write a comment `// this is a comment` compile to `<!-- this is a comment -->`
- to write class name and content for tag  for example `p.demo this is a paragraph` compile to `<p class="demo"> this is a paragraph</p>`
- to write id and content for tag  for example `p#demo this is a paragraph` compile to `<p id="demo"> this is a paragraph</p>`
- to write a function

  `mixin list
        ul
          li foo
          li bar
          li baz`

to use this function write the name of function `+list` and will compile to

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
  </ul>
```

to include file write `include file_name`

Finally this is a example for pug code

```
html 
    head
        title Hello
        link(href='' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
    body

        //this is a comment
        p.item hello
        p#item

        br/

        a(href='#' target=''): img(src='' alt='') 
        // to start a new line
        |
        |
        a(href='google.com') Google
         // write a function
         mixin list
          ul
            li foo
            li bar
            li baz
        // use function
        +list
        // include file
        include content
```

For more information about pug check this link [pug full documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Jade is now called "pug".

> npm install pug -g

Here you will find how to use it if you scroll down:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug